# Problems with findBeans Spring

Tags: java, spring

- I'm trying to check a password change in Active Directory from a Java
  application developed with Spring to an identity management
  application (OPENIAM). I have to use a service called
  AuditDataService by calling findBeans and filling the
  "AuditLogSearchBean" filter with at least the following parameters:

  - setUserId(String userId) : Id of the user
  - setTargetUsers(Set targetUsers): User on which the action is executed
  - setActions(Set actions) : A collection with the action
  - setTargetManagedSystems(Set targetManagedSystems) : Managed system identifier collection, in this case AD only
  - setFrom : Date, which would be the day of the change (today)

My problem is that the AuditLogSearchBean class does not have a setTargetUsers, setActions and setTargetManagedSystems, it only contains setUserId and setFrom, in the API I see this:

```
public class AuditLogSearchBean
extends AbstractSearchBean<IdmAuditLogDoc,String>
```

IdmAuditLogDoc has the sets I need but I can't get to them.

service call in the Controller:

```
AuditDataService auditDataService = (AuditDataService)context.getBean("auditDataService");
            AuditLogSearchBean alsb = new AuditLogSearchBean();
            alsb.setUserId(user.getId());

            auditDataService.findBeans(alsb, 0, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

AuditLogSearchBean java class code:

[image]

IdmAuditLogDoc java class code:

[image]

Comment: You should review the Spring Getting Started guides to go over basic concepts. Any time you're calling `getBean`, you're usually using Spring wrong. In most cases, dependencies should be passed as constructor parameters to the services that need them.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Thank you